# Setting "!important" via Jquery for tag with dynamic height : Not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script:

```
     box.copyHeight = function() {
      var heights = [],
        i, hT;
      for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if ($(arguments[i])) {
          $(arguments[i]).css('height', '');
          if ($(arguments[i])[0] !== undefined) {
            heights.unshift($(arguments[i]).height());
          }
        }
      }
      hT = heights.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
      }).reverse()[0]; //ninja *[1]
      for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if ($(arguments[i])) {
          $(arguments[i]).css('height', hT + 'px');
        }
      }
      return hT;
    };
```

and this line is to call myfunction

```
box.copyHeight('article','aside');
```

It's a function, which sets height to `<article>` and `<aside>`, always respecting who has the highest value.
My problem is that it's not working only in IE 11.
After some debugging, I reached a very simple solution, which is set !important to the height style.
My doubt is, how to do it via jquery, more specifically in this line

```
$(arguments[i]).css('height','');
```

My current output is `<article style="700px">` and `<aside style="700px">`, and it need to be
`<article style="700px!important">` and `<aside style="700px!important">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(arguments[i]).css('height', hT + 'px !important');
```

Comment: the height is not fixed, It can be 700px, or 800, 1500px, 2000px, etc. I cant do this.

Comment: I've just tried this few seconds before u typed! hehe, worked! tks :)